# What is the use of SuiteBuilders and TestCaseBuilder in NNUnit?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Thanks in Advance!

I am new to NUnit + selenium having worked throughout my experience in TestNG+Selenium+Java.
Having googled lot of sites I want to know what is the use of SuiteBuilders and TestCaseBuilder in NUnit.

Any code example and reference will be of great use.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague, but maybe a vague answer will lead to some clarification, so here goes:

**ISuiteBuilder** is an interface within the nunit framework, which is implemented by a class that knows how to build a test suite from a user-provided class. It is currently only implemented by the internal class **DefaultSuiteBuilder**.

Similarly, **ITestCaseBuilder** is an interface implemented by classes that know how to build a test case from a user-provided method. It too is only implemented by one internal class: **DefaultTestCaseBuilder**.

Interfaces of the same names also existed in NUnit V2. Under V2, you were allowed to write your own classes that implemented these interfaces and install them as **Addins**. NUnit V2 and it's addin facility are pretty much obsolete after seven releases of NUnit 3. We consider V2 to be legacy code and don't do bug fixes in it any longer. NUnit 3 extensibility takes a different approach from NUnit 2.

I haven't expanded on any of this, because I can't tell exactly what you are asking about. If you can clarify your question and explain what you want to accomplish, I'll try to replace this answer with one that's more helpful.

**Note:** Since you are new to NUnit, you should make sure you are looking at documentation for the version you are using. Google searches can easily lead you to older docs. If you have a choice, you should use the latest version. You can easily navigate to the docs for any version by starting at http://nunit.org.